# SSIS derived column convert string to date

Tags: ssis, bids

I am trying to convert a string into Date using Derived column and I am using Flat File Source.
I read bunch of articles on stackoverflow and followed the same steps but I am unable to convert my string into date format.

Here is the string

```
Tue Nov 25 17:32:03 EST 2008
```

And I want to show it like

```
2008-nov-25
```

I tried using the following code

```
(DT_DBDATE)(SUBSTRING(dateCreated,24,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(dateCreated,4,3) + "-" +    SUBSTRING(dateCreated,8,2))
```

I also tried to use

```
  (DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING(dateCreated,24,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(dateCreated,4,3) + "-" +    SUBSTRING(dateCreated,8,2))

  (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING(dateCreated,24,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(dateCreated,4,3) + "-" +    SUBSTRING(dateCreated,8,2))
```

Is this the correct way to convert the string into date format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think its possible to display the in the format of yyyy-mon-dd as per [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). I checked your expression and after minor changes, was able to make it to work. You cannot typecast your string into a string again (You want month name in your output). Even if you were to use the DATEPART function, it would again amount to concatenating different parts into a string.

The expression that works with your input is as follows (replace @dateCreated with whatever you want to).

```
SUBSTRING(@[User::dateCreated],24,5) + "-" + SUBSTRING(@[User::dateCreated],4,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(@[User::dateCreated],8,3)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked fine. I am able to save the dates in destination table.But my column has datetime datatype. So it is now saving the as
2008-11-25 00:00:00.000. So Can I use the SUBSTRING to get time as well from my string? So that the final output is like 2008-11-25 17:32:03

Comment: Yes. You can very well do that. If your destination is DATETIME field, cast the above expression completely to a DB_DATETIME.

Comment: I think there is no typecasting function like DB_DATETIME in derived column Type Casts list.

Comment: Sorry I was my mistake it is working now. Thanks for your help 
@Rajiv Varma

Comment: Thanks Rajiv!

So The final expression which gives the desired result is:-

    (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING(dateCreated,24,5) + "-" + SUBSTRING(dateCreated,4,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(dateCreated,8,3) + " " + SUBSTRING(dateCreated,11,9))

The input being :-

    Tue Nov 25 17:32:03 EST 2008

And the output is:-

    2008-11-25 17:47:41.000

Comment: Awesome!! Keep posting more questions ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rajiv!

So The final expression which gives the desired result is:-

```
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING(dateCreated,24,5) + "-" + SUBSTRING(dateCreated,4,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(dateCreated,8,3) + " " + SUBSTRING(dateCreated,11,9))
```

The input being :-

```
Tue Nov 25 17:47:41 EST 2008
```

And the output is:-

```
2008-11-25 17:47:41.000
```